# What is the difference between a binary tree and just a regualr tree?

Tags: c++

Binary tree i know can have at most two children and a struct for a binarty tree looks like :

```
Struct BinaryNode
{
    Object element;
    BinaryNode *left;
    BinaryNode *right;
}
```

How would the struct for a treeNode looks like?..

Comment: Define "regular tree".

Comment: @HotLicks a tree that can have many children

Comment: A general tree needs to be able to handle more than two children.

Comment: so i guess i'm confused about is .. how would u create a struct for that?..

Comment: Are we talking coniferous or deciduous?

Comment: One way to create a struct for that is to use a struct that has inside a std::set<BinaryNode *> of all children pointers.

Comment: There are many, many styles of trees.  There is no such thing as a "regular tree".  In particular, if a node can have more than two children there are many different ways to choose how the children are selected.  Not to mention the fact that there can trees where non-leaf nodes contain no data, and those where they may contain data.  (And a binary tree can also have multiple variations -- in particular, radix vs balanced vs something else.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, a tree consists of nodes which can have child nodes with a couple of constraints to ensure that the data structure is "tree shaped":

- every node has one parent node ... apart from the root node which has no parent.
- there are no cycles.

A binary tree is just a tree in which each node can have *at most* 2 children.

---

The analogous `struct` declaration for a general tree node would be something like this:

```
struct Node
{
    Object element;
    Node **children;
}
```

where `children` refers to an array of nodes ... though it probably ought to be some kind of managed collection of `Node` pointers.  If you use a collection, it is conceptually a "set" but you are unlikely to rely on the "set-like" properties in the tree implementation.  It is more important that the collection is ordered / order preserving.

Comment: So how would you go about creating a struct for a tree (like the one i have for BinaryNode above), what do u do to account for the many number of children it can have?

Comment: @psj01:  Search the web for "b-tree data structure".

Answer (score 3):

A binary tree is just what the name says: Binary! Two (bi..) children per node. In graphics there are often tree called QuadTrees or OctTrees. There every node has 4 or 8 children. So a general tree is a data structure where every node has "some number of" children. In a binary tree that number is always 2.

Answer (score -1):

Binary tree is kind of regular tree only. Which is constrained to
have at most two child and it is not the constraint with all the trees.